# Как хранить данные textbox в блокноте и потом вызывать их?

Tags: c#

Как хранить данные textbox в блокноте и потом вызывать их? При том в строгом порядке. Чтобы при закрытии программы он сохранял, записывал данные туда. А при запуске, они оказались в своих местах, с последнего сеанса. Как будто приложение и не закрывалось

Comment: Хранить данные в блокноте? Вызывать их? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Flammable: по ходу ТС не видит разницы между форматом файла и приложением, умеющим его обрабатывать. facepalm.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте событие при закрытии формы (Form Closing) и впишите в него такой код:

```
if (!File.Exists("textboxFile.txt"))
    File.Create("textboxFile.txt").Close();
File.WriteAllText("textboxFile.txt", textBox1.Text);
```

Данный метод будет проверять наличие файла **textboxFile.txt** и создавать его, если он не существовал. Затем запишет туда содержимое **textBox1**.

Затем создайте событие, которое будет запускаться при открытии формы (Form Load). Вставьте туда код:

```
if (File.Exists("textboxFile.txt"))
    textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText("textboxFile.txt");
```

Если файл **textboxFile.txt** существует, то данный метод возьмет оттуда данные и запишет их в **textBox1**.

**UPDATED:** как бы я быстро накодил кучу TextBox'ов записывать в текстовый файл.
Берем все контролы с формы при закрытии формы (Form Closing), которые являются текстбоксами и записываем их в файл, который будет иметь имя в виде имени текстбокса:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
   if (c is TextBox)
   {
       if (!File.Exists(c.Name + ".txt"))
           File.Create(c.Name + ".txt").Close();
       File.WriteAllText(c.Name + ".txt", c.Text);
   }
```

При открытии формы (Form Load) создаем новый Текстбокс и помещаем его на форму:

```
string[] textBoxFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath, "*.txt");
foreach (string textBoxFile in textBoxFiles)
{
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    string filename = new FileInfo(textBoxFile).Name;
    tb.Name = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf('.'));
    tb.Parent = this;
    tb.Text = File.ReadAllText(textBoxFile);
}
```

Только в последнем листинге надо ещё указать позицию текстобоксов, а то они могут друг на друга наложиться. Я думаю, вы это сами сделаете.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А как сделать, если у меня несколько тексбоксов, динамических, в зависимости сколько раз нажмет на кнопку пользователь. Как сделать тогда, чтобы в каждый тестбокс записывался определенный текст? Может быть нумерованный или как то по другому

Comment: В следующий раз задавайте вопрос полностью сразу,дабы можно было давать ответ на него, а не апдейтить вопрос по нескольку раз или, хуже того, в комментариях давать полный ответ.

Comment: Хорошо. Поможете?

Comment: Чем смог - тем помог.

Comment: Спасибо! Дальше сам разберусь

Comment: @Drac5: писать в каталог установки программы (а тем более в случайный текущий каталог) -- плохая идея. Program Files обычно не доступен для записи. Лучше уж использовать %APPDATA%. Ещё лучше хранить значения не в файле, а в settings'ах.